# How do I bend pipes with Blender modelling tools?

Tags: modeling

Here's a screenshot of my model so far. I can select vector points in edit mode but can't move them. I'm working on a MacBook Pro laptop.Is there any way of uploading and sharing Blender model files on this forum?[image]

Comment: That depends on the method that you are modelling your pipes. can you share a screenshot and/or your blend-file of what you have so far?

Comment: Thanks v much for the screenshots! I'll try this method.  : ) I have accidentally deleted my previous files. I remember selecting end vertices and using spin but I wasn't in the correct view mode so I was getting  some pretty wild results. My shape need to be straight, then bent quite sharply, then straight for a bit then bent sharply again, a bit like an unfolded twisted paperclip.

Comment: For sharply bend you can use the same method in my answer and set the shape of the curve to 2D, then select all the curve handler and set them to vector.

Answer (score 1):

there is different ways to do what you want in blender, one of them is this one:

1. Add a new bezier circle:
   [image]
2. Add a new bezier curve:
   [image]
3. With the bezier curve selected, go to Properties menu > Object data > Bevel > Object
   [image]
4. Select the bezier circle you previously create.
   [image]
   [image]
5. Now the bezier curve looks like a thick pipe.
   [image]
6. You can adjust the pipe thickness by reducing or increasing the bezier circle radius[image]
7. Now you can manipulate the bezier curve as you want to simulate the pipe bend effect.
   [image]

For more information about bezier curves visit:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/curves/structure.html#bezier-curves